# Provisioning profile doesn't support the Keychain Sharing capability and missing entitlements

Tags: ios, xcode

I have recently started programming and developing for iOS. The apps I made previously have worked and have built on my phone, but when developing my most recent app, I ran into two fatal issues, namely [two missing entitlements and no support for the Keychain Sharing capability](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwLSg.png), and could not run it on my phone, but said app worked just fine on the simulator.

It appears that the issue now affects all my projects, as I can't build previous apps directly on my phone, and after scouring the internet for fixes, I am at my wits end. I would appreciate it if someone could help me...Thank you :)

P.S I am running Xcode 10.1, and my iPhone is running iOS 12.1.